# Parsing command line argument in BATCH file

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch

I have picked up following example to understand parsing of command line argument in BATCH file:

```
@echo off

:Help
echo sumit

:GETOPTS
if /I "%1" == "-h" call :Help
if /I "%1" == "-b" set BASE=%2 & shift
if /I "%1" == "-s" set SQL=%2 & shift
shift
if not "%1" == "" goto GETOPTS

echo %BASE%
echo %SQL%
```

Now, have few issues with it, :Help is called even if I don't pass -h option to my batch file during execution.

How it could be avoided ?

```
optgets.bat -b milan -s okaz
sumit
milan
okaz
```

It shouldn't print sumit as I didn't pass -h option

Second, once done with execution it should unset the variable being set using command line arguments

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/811835/passing-command-line-arguments-to-a-windows-batch-script?rq=1 Maybe that will help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in order to debug your original Source Code File, you can simply skip the initial `echo` Command using a `goto` Command:

```
@echo off

goto GETOPTS

:Help
echo sumit

:GETOPTS
if /I "%1" == "-h" call :Help
if /I "%1" == "-b" set BASE=%2 & shift
if /I "%1" == "-s" set SQL=%2 & shift
shift
if not "%1" == "" goto GETOPTS

echo %BASE%
echo %SQL%
```

Can you please explain what you have meant through the following paragraph?

> Second, once done with execution it should unset the variable being
>   set using command line arguments.

Answer (score 3):

This batch file will *always* do the `echo sumit` since it is the first thing in
the file.

You surely meant something like:

```
@echo off

:GETOPTS
if /I "%1" == "-h" goto Help
if /I "%1" == "-b" set BASE=%2 & shift
if /I "%1" == "-s" set SQL=%2 & shift
shift
if not "%1" == "" goto GETOPTS

echo %BASE%
echo %SQL%
exit

:Help
echo sumit
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because something is under a label doesn't mean that the label is treated like a function to be called. You would need to use a `goto GETOPTS` before the `:help` line. (cmd.exe doesn't have the concept of 'call', either, so you'd need to use `goto` where you currently have `call`.)

For your second question, it is possible to make environment changes local to the cmd file (or even regions of the cmd file) by using the `SETLOCAL` command.